# Do we have to write custom code to get access token while using authorization_code grant type in oauth 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am new to using OAuth 2 and wanted to know if we need to write custom code in order to exchange the authorization code and access token or does spring boot completes this exchange on its own?

Comment: Try it and you will get an answer. You don't need any custom codes but if you need to extract or map some information like user's roles, you will need to add custom codes.

Comment: I am trying to set the Principal object after the user is authorized by the authorization server. Do I still need to add a custom code?

Comment: I have seen in multiple videos that this context setting is done automatically by adding @EnableOAuth2Ssso. Is this the only thing we have to do or there is more to it?

Comment: Again give a try and you will have an answer. Try something and if you have strange results then come back here and ask a question.